# Estimating IRT item parameters when ability is known

Tags: r, item-response-theory

I'm reading the Fundamentals of IRT book by Hambleton et al. In this book they demonstrate the invariance of item parameters in a 3PL model by:

1. First building the model on the full sample, deriving both item
   parameters and an ability estimate for each examinee.
2. then splitting the sample into two subsamples - a high performing subsample and a low performing subsample.
3. then re-estimating the item parameters seperately on each sample using the known ability estimates from the first analysis.

I am attempting to reproduce this analysis using mirt / ltm in R, however I can't find a way to pass known ability estimates (e.g. factor scores) to the mirt / ltm functions, so that the item parameter estimation can take place with known ability estimates.

Any assistance in doing this would be much apprecaited!

Anthony.

Comment: I don't think you need to use IRT packages to see this effect. If the ability parameters are known the setup reduces basically to a logistic regression (if all the IRT models were from the 2PLM family), where you can treat the population ability terms as a fixed and known independent variable. Then, regardless of the ability subset you take, you should obtain unbiased estimates of the IRT item parameters in each sample. Package's like mirt/ltm don't really support this type of input since IRT model are only estimated in situations where the latent trait values are unknown to begin with.

Comment: Thank you @philchalmers - that makes sense :)

Comment: @philchalmers, thank you for the response! Maybe you should answer directly, would be an amazing answer. O got it regarding 2PLM but if I have the 3 parameter logistic model?